# Change network interface for multicast subscription

Tags: linux, networking, linux-networking, multicast

My laptop has 2 network interfaces: ethernet (eno1, 600 Metric) and wireless (wlo1, 1000 Metric)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.200.100.1    0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlo1
10.200.100.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlo1
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 eno1
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     100    0        0 eno1
```

I receive multicast stream via ethernet (can confirm via wireshark) but when I try to render it using vlc, I can't. The reason is multicast gets subscribed via wlo1, not ethernet that stream is coming from.

```
IPv6/IPv4 Group Memberships
Interface       RefCnt Group
--------------- ------ ---------------------
lo              1      224.0.0.251
lo              1      all-systems.mcast.net
eno1            2      224.0.0.251
eno1            1      all-systems.mcast.net
wlo1            1      234.5.5.5  <------- MY STREAM
```

Why this happens? How can I force Linux to subscribe to multicast on ethernet?
 Any help is appreciated.

P.S. when I disable wireless, multicast doesn't subscribe at any interface at all.

Comment: How do you (try to) subscribe to that multicast stream?

Comment: @Tommiie I just open vlc and try to render the stream

Comment: Before opening the vlc there is no subscription in `netstat -g`. When I open the vlc and try to render the stream, `netstat -g` shows multicast subscription in wireless interface instead of ethernet

Comment: I found temporary solution but it's not enough. I need permanent solution. I'm gonna share the command so that it may solve somone's problem: `sudo ip route add multicast 234.5.5.5 dev eno1` (eno1 is my ethernet, you may change it to yours)